tidymodels / shapviz::shapviz: Error in s[, nms, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
When I run shapviz::shapviz, I get the error:

Error in s[, nms, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions

I believe I am using the correct predictors for the model, which are being "retained" for me by recipes::bake.
I'm also removing NAs, just incase.
Any idea what is going on here?

syllable_mod <- bundle::unbundle(lyricassessr::syllable_classifier_bundle)

# The tidymodels prediction works:

  preds <- predict(syllable_mod, new_data = audio_features, type = "prob") %>%
    dplyr::rename_with(~stringr::str_remove_all(.x, ".pred_")) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(dplyr::everything(),
                        names_to = "Syllable", values_to = "Probability") %>%
    dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(Probability))

  xgb_model <- parsnip::extract_fit_engine(syllable_mod)

# Make sure there are no NAs, just incase (1 is a meaningless number for now..)
  audio_features <- audio_features %>%
    dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 1, .x)))

  audio_features_prepped <- recipes::bake(
    lyricassessr::prepped_recipe,
    recipes::has_role("predictor"),
    new_data = audio_features) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 1, .x)))

# Make sure audio_features agree with the retained (prepped) features
  audio_features <- audio_features %>%
    dplyr::select(dplyr::all_of(names(audio_features_prepped)))


shap_values <- shapviz::shapviz(xgb_model, X_pred = as.matrix(audio_features_prepped), X = as.matrix(audio_features))



The code is not complete.
SHAP values returned by XGBoost lose a dimension with single-row X_pred. This leads to the problem.
Fixed in https://github.com/ModelOriented/shapviz/pull/142
